# TinyMCE custom toolbar button event

Tags: events, onclick, tinymce, toolbar

I have to access to button's `onClick event`, something like `event.target`. When adding button to toolbar we have onAction handler that doesn't expose `onClick event` but have only `isEnabled` and `setEnabled` methods. I can access to `window.event`, but that is deprecated. So the code would be something like:

````
editor.ui.registry.addButton('button', {
    text: 'Button text',
    icon: 'icon',
    onAction: (api:ToolbarButtonInstanceApi) => { // Here I have access to only button 
                                                  //api, but I need access to event as 
                                                  //well so I can use it as event.currentTarget
    },
});```

How could I access to `onClick event`?
````

Answer (score 0):

I've been researching this too as I needed to do something similar, or at least find a way of accessing the button node when it's clicked, so far I've not come up with anything that can be used inside the onAction handler, and attempting to access .this inside that arrow head function will give you the global window details. I feel there must be some way!